# ZFS Mirror on same drive for redundancy?

Tags: debian, raid, zfs

The device I would like to use as a home server has only a single 2.5'' internal hard drive bay currently fitted with 1TB. The actual data storage (2x 1TB) will be attached to the external USB 3.0 ports.

The external drives are 3.5 server-grade, advertised to be 24/7 capable. The internal 2.5 drive is only desktop-grade.

After trying BTRFS I'm now exploring my options with ZFS due to higher maturity of ZFS.

First idea was to only mirror the data on the external drives and install the OS (debian 8) to the internal drive. This is easy enough but leaves the OS vulnerable to disk failure.

Next idea is to boot from the external mirror and leave the internal drive unused or for tmp, swap, unimportant stuff.

Next idea: create a 3-way mirror out of the single internal and dual external drives and boot from the mirror. This seemed to be cheap enough since I already have the drives and could get some reliability and possibly read performance at virtually no cost. Total capacity would be still 1TB obviously.

This 3-way mirror however limits by options in terms of extensibility because ZFS requires all drives in a mirror to be equal size and thus when I want to grow the array I am stuck with what 2.5'' drives I can get hold of. 2.5'' drives are seemingly only available up to 2TB while 3.5'' drives up to 4TB seem already common enough. Also, with a 2-way mirror of external drives only I could doubly my capacity later by creating a RAID10 with an additional 2 drives...

Also I am slightly unsure whether miggling OS and data in one pool is really a good idea. Still I don't feel that leaving the OS unprotected on the least reliable drive in my setup seems a bit of a gambit.

This leaves me with a slightly strange option: mirror my OS data on the single internal drive. That is create two partitions on the 2.5'' intnernal HDD and combine them into a mirror. I would hope that this gave me kind of an early warning in case the drive was about to fail assuming that the drives does not go up in smoke but failed gradually. At the same time the external drives would hold movies, pictures, music, etc separate from the OS.

Which option would you choose? Is the last one effective or is my reasoning simply wrong?

Comment: You could leverage the `copies` attribute and set it to e.g. `2` for the boot disk to have a least some sort of redundancy. Or boot from USB sticks or SATA DOMs which you can easily mirror. I personally would ditch the external disks and invest in a proper server grade motherboard and run FreeNAS from two mirrored USB drives and attach the two server grade disks to the SATA ports. But you could also set up a similar system using Debian as OS.

Comment: I just learned about the ´copies` property. Exactly what I was after..

Answer (score 2):

To add some information besides the `copies=2` solution:

> This 3-way mirror however limits by options in terms of extensibility because ZFS requires all drives in a mirror to be equal size and thus when I want to grow the array I am stuck with what 2.5'' drives I can get hold of. 2.5'' drives are seemingly only available up to 2TB while 3.5'' drives up to 4TB seem already common enough. Also, with a 2-way mirror of external drives only I could doubly my capacity later by creating a RAID10 with an additional 2 drives...

That is not 100% correct.

- All devices in a mirrored vdev need to have the same or bigger size as the smallest device in this vdev. The storage capacity of the vdev will then be exactly the size of this smallest device. So for 3 disks with 1, 1.5 and 2 TB, you can have a vdev size of 1TB. If you only had the 1.5 and 2 TB disks with a size of 1.5, you cannot add the smaller 1 TB disk later (but you could add bigger disks at any time).
- Mirrors are flexible: in contrast to raidz, where you must upgrade all disks of the vdev to the larger size, in a mirror you can remove disks at any time. So, again with the example of 1, 1.5 and 2 TB disks in the mirror, you remove the first two disks and add a new 2 TB disk. You lose some redundancy, but do not need to restore the whole pool or have the same amount of disks as before.
- When looking at the pool level, you can pair any and all vdev sizes and types, although it is typically not recommended because of performance and redundancy reasons. But it is perfectly possible to create a pool of 3 vdevs - a single disk of 4TB, a raidz3 with 3 disks of 3TB each and a mirror with 2 disks of 2TB each, resulting in 4+6+2=12 TB of usable pool space. Of course, if the 4TB disk dies, all your data is lost, regardless of the redundancy level of the other 2 vdevs... so this is not recommended. Also note that ZFS does not rebalance old existing data like with hardware raid controllers.

> Also I am slightly unsure whether miggling OS and data in one pool is really a good idea. Still I don't feel that leaving the OS unprotected on the least reliable drive in my setup seems a bit of a gambit.

I propose four different solutions (in order of how I would choose them in your case):

1. Buy a quality SLC memory USB 3.0 stick with 8, 16 or 32 GB depending on your needs, and install the operating system (i recommend OmniOS + napp-it, but you may also use Linux) on that stick. It will be a bit slower than a harddisk or real SSD, but it saves your valuable slots. You can also do it via internal pin headers to remove access to the stick. Then you could buy another one exactly like that and mirror the boot drive. This way, you can even do a manual image backup from time to time, or replace the hardware without shutting down the system or needing hotplug-capable SATA/SAS controllers.
2. Use a system that lives entirely in RAM and saves all your configuration and data on the pool itself. You can boot this via a cheap USB stick or via network (PXE). SmartOS comes to mind, you might want to read about it [here](https://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/Is+SmartOS+suitable+for+a+file+server)
3. Depending on your hardware, it may be possible to fit 2 slim 2.5" drives into on slot (some modification may be needed). There exist 1TB drives with 7 mm and 2TB drives with 9 mm height. Of course, you would need 2 SATA ports for that.
4. Do not care about the OS drive. As ZFS holds most of the interesting stuff already on the pool itself, you may be perfectly fine without any mirrors. Do a regular scrub (it will detect errors, although it cannot correct them) and if the scrub is without errors, copy your important system and config files over to a filesystem on the (mirrored) data pool. Alternatively you can do a file system image and store it in the data pool. In case of disk failure, use a Live CD to import your data pool and restore the saved backup.

Comment: To try and clarify #4.
If the pool has no redundancy, it will detect and not be able to fix the issue without a mirror or parity bits to fix.
However, obviously a dead disk is a dead disk.

Comment: @sleepyweasel Reading my post again, I see that the quote was mangled and that it made my intention of the 4 parts unclear. Thanks for your highlight, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Which option would I choose?

That would all depend on how important your data is.  And ***when*** a drive dies (even the most expensive enterprise drive you can buy will fail at some point.  After all, it's just spinning rust.), can you live without the data if you don't have a backup of it?

You'll find various suggestions out there, but most will reco using a mirror, or even a triple mirror--to avoid the parity rebuild time of a RAID5 type configuration.  Drives keep getting bigger, and luckily their cost is staying reasonable.  The mirror also gives you an easier upgrade path -- since you need a drive of the same or larger size.

A common practice is to try and not mirror two drives from the same manufacturers build.  I've got a friend that goes further and replaces his drives after a period of time (2 years?) assuming it will fail.

I also forgot to note that another advantage to using ZFS to mirror two system drives vs using hw raid in the server is that ZFS can then detect and fix any possible errors it encounters.